# Route all subdomains to their same-name folders

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express app and want to route each subdomain to the corresponding folder of my filesystem. For instance, GET on `example.com` would look for file in `./`, while `blog.example.com` would look for file in `./blog/`, etc.

With this code I can append the subdomain to the requested route:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){ 
  if(req.headers.host.indexOf('.example.com') > -1)
    req.url = '/' + req.headers.host.split('.')[0] + req.url
  next()
})
```

But then I have to add `app.use('/blog', express.static('./blog'))` for the blog, `app.use('/docs', express.static('./docs'))` for the docs, etc. I have to name each one of them.

How can I do a `app.use('/*', express.static('./*'))` ?

Answer (score 0):

`app.use('/', express.static('.'))` seems to do just that.